# JavaScript replace issue and return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to replace simple text [debit] but it return undefined.
Any guesses.

```
var totalDebit = 0;    
$("input[name$='[debit]']").each(function() {

  if ($(this).attr('name') && $(this).attr('name').match(/items\[\d+\]\[debit\]/)) {
        // var exchange_rate =  $("input[name='items["+i+"][exchange_rate]']").val(); // get exchange_rate
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        alert( name );

        var res = name.replace("[debit]");


        console.log( res );
        alert( res );
        totalDebit += $(this).val() ? parseInt($(this).val()) : 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace takes two arguments; the string to replace, and the string to replace it with.

Comment: `"this is a [debit] test".replace("[debit]")` gives "this is a undefined test" because of the missing second parameter to replace.

Comment: What are you trying to replace it with?

Comment: @James thanks you are right just tested it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The replace function takes in a second argument. In this case, you did not pass in a second argument to replace and so '[debit]' is replaced with undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` expects a second argument - which is the new value. In your case I will do:

`name.replace("[debit]","")`

This should fix the `undefined` you won't like to see.